# Which smtplib exception does an AWS SES throttling failure raise?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

According to the AWS SES [SMTP issues doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-smtp.html), a "Maximum send rate exceeded" response is accompanied by the `454 Throttling failure: Maximum sending rate exceeded` response code. If this occurs while I'm using SES's SMTP interface, with Python's `smtplib`, to send mail, which specific exception will I get?

[RFC 4954](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4954#section-6) says that status code 454 is a "Temporary authentication failure". Does that mean I'll get `SMTPAuthenticationError`? I'm thinking it might be something else, like `SMTPDataError`, as throttling isn't exactly an authentication issue (though it's related), but I'm not familiar with the protocol and its exact steps.

I've been unable to actually trigger a throttling event with the SES SMTP interface as AWS doesn't always strictly enforce max sending rates.